# How to choose the right flexible cable for moving parts?

Tags: cables, component-selection, standard, flexible, harsh-environment

Is there a generally accepted guide to select a cable, which has to withstand certain bending stress?

I am looking for something like this:

```
IEC 12345-6
Wire rigidity 
How many bending cycles between straight wire and a bow with R = 10 x diameter can 
the wire withstand until 1 out of 100 wires fail.
class | cycles 
A     | 1
B     | 100
C     | 10000
D     | 1000000
```

Is there any related standard in IEC, MIL, DIN, ISO...?

Comment: Solud or multi-stranded?

Comment: @SolarMike I did not expect that solid wires would be used in flexible cables, but if they are mentioned in the standard it would be interesting too.

Comment: don't know the answer, but if you look at the datasheet of a common 'flexible conduit compatible' cable product, e.g. Phoenix Contact # 1522516, and follow the trail... note it specifies bend radius and cycles. Further, the actual cable portion is specified, in this case,  by Helukabel/Sensorflex, code Li9Y11Y. Follow the trail from there, perhaps.

Comment: @PeteW Thanks a lot for the product suggestions. These datasheets are a good start.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Minimum Bend Radius (Flexing). Manufacturers usually specify their flexing and static bend radius.
The lesser the bend radius, more flexible the cable is.
Also, Static bend radius is for fixed applications, whereas flexing bend radius is for moving applications.

This snip is from a cable manufacturer called Huber+Suhner from their Radox155 Automotive High voltage cable.
[image]

As for the standards, I am not really sure. A quick google search for IEC or DIN standard can provide you more info. Also, you can check up on standards related to the application where you are planning to use these cables.

Comment: I did not find the right IEC, DIN, ISO ... standard with search engines. Perhaps I tried the wrong words. But it is difficult to search for a standard unless you have the exact name or number already.

Comment: True, but I would just give you an example on how to proceed with this. Consider that I am working on sizing High voltage cables for an installation. What I would do is go search for "High Voltage Cable sizing standards". This would give me a lot of results, some of them irrelevant. INSTEAD, if I go to the cable catalogs and see the standards THEY have used, that would actually help me find the right standard much faster. This is what I actually did when I was searching for cable sizing standards. I found out about IEC 60287 standard for finding current rating of HV cables from cable catalogs